# Loop that generates random numbers and print when condition is true

Tags: java, math

I have got a problem with generating a loop that will provide me with a random numbers that are going to fulfil my condition.

Example:

> Generate two Numbers in the bound (401)+100 and print numbers when int
>   `a` is going to be bigger than `b`

Program should work until the condition is going to be true. I was thinking that i should use "while" loop but its not going well. 
Thank you for answer.

```
 import java.util.Random;

    public class Ex7 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int a = rand.nextInt(401) + 100;
        int b = rand.nextInt(401) + 100;
        while (a > b) {
            System.out.println("B value: " + b);
        }

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an infinite loop that stops when the condition is true, is that what you are looking for?

```
Random rand = new Random();
int a,b;
while(true)
{
    a = rand.nextInt(401) + 100;
    b = rand.nextInt(401) + 100;
    if(a>b) {
        System.out.println("B value: " + b);
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
If you don't want it to stop, then simply remove `break`

Answer (score 0):

Because after the first time you enter your 'While Loop', you did not reassign a new value to a and b, so if a is bigger than b the first time, it will just print forever, whereas if b is bigger than a the first time, it will never print anything. A quick fix is to reassign the value again in the while-loop after printing!

```
    while (a > b) {
        System.out.println("B value: " + b);
        a = rand.nextInt(401) + 100;
        b = rand.nextInt(401) + 100;
    }
```

Comment: Better use `do { ... } while(...);` here instead of `while`, since `a` and `b` are unassigned before the loop. Or initialise `a` and `b` first.

Answer (score 0):

> Program should work until the condition is going to be true. I was thinking that i should use "while" loop but its not going well

In your current code, the random values for `a` and `b` were only generated once and does not get updated. Hence if `a` happens to be greater than `b`, you get infinite loop with infinite print outputs. 
If `a` happens to be smaller than `b`, you don't get any output at all.

You need to re-randomize the value of `a` and `b` after each round of the looping.

The catch of using `while-loop` is that you need to ensure the loop condition evaluates to `true` (i.e., `a` is greater than `b`) in order for the codes in the loop to be executed.

To overcome this, you can use `do-while-loop` so you don't have the worry about the initial values for `a` and `b`:

```
public class Ex7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        do{                             //run first                
            a = rand.nextInt(401) + 100;
            b = rand.nextInt(401) + 100;
            System.out.println("B value: " + b);
        }while (a > b);                 //then check condition whether to continue running
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using `do`/`while` then the `= 0` initial values are unnecessary, because they'll be assigned in the loop before the condition is checked anyway.

Comment: Personal preference. For me I would prefer to initialize the variables for better program predictability.

Comment: What do you mean by "predictability"? The behaviour of the program is exactly the same whether or not you write `= 0` in those variable declarations; they are [dead stores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_store).